# Java and C++ Shared Memory

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, ipc, shared-memory

I have a C++ piece of code that creates shared memory. Is it possible to write Java Code which  can read the memory created by the C++ code unless using JNI. By the way I am using Windows OS.

Comment: To use native memory without using native interface?

Comment: Access to [off heap memory](http://code.google.com/p/fast-serialization/wiki/QuickStartHeapOff) could be the answer.

Comment: Yes I wonder about is there a standart java library for that thing.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729808/java-unmanaged-memory-stream and reference to Unsafe.

Answer (score 5):

See [`MappedByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).  It's the standard Java class to read & write shared memory. I use it a lot. Yes, you can use this to communicate with any program written in any language which uses shared memory, and it's all very standard Java, no JNI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use code project :[code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2460/Using-Memory-Mapped-Files-and-JNI-to-communicate-b)